# how to catch closing models eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, listener

I would like to do some stuff when I'm closing "MyModel" UML project in the Project explorer. I tryed IResourceChangeListener  but it works only for "MyProject" . So tu sum up : how to catch "action close"  of ProjectExplorer->MyProject->Models->MyModel ?

Comment: IResourceChangeListener reports every file, folder and project that is modified. You must look inside the resource change event at **all** the event deltas.

Comment: the problem is that resourceChanged() is only call for MyProject change state  , not for "MyModel" So I think the problem come from the listener

Comment: I'm not clear what you are saying. When a file is changed the resource change event will contain entries for the project, any folders and the file.